# select where substring

Tags: sql, oracle

SQL newbie here, but I can't find the solution to something that looks easy:

The following query does not seem to have a valid syntax (ORA-00904: invalid identifier), but its logic should be clear. How can I achieve this in a query that needs to be speedy?

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE LEFT(column,4)="abcd"
```

Comment: is your database `MS SQL` or `oracle`?

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/sql_elements003.htm#SQLRF00218

Comment: Oracle doesn't support `left()`.  Use `substr()` instead.  But that isn't the best way to express this.

Comment: My database is oracle

Comment: In case you're wondering, the `ORA-00904` is due to the identifier `"abcd"` which you probably intended to be a string literal `'abcd'`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For this purpose, you should use `like` rather than `left()`.  First, Oracle doesn't support `left()` (you need `substr()` instead).  Second, `like` can make use of indexes because the wildcard is not at the beginning of the string:

```
SELECT *
FROM table
WHERE column like 'abcd%';
```

Comment: `'LIKE'` is a better option from performance point of view +1

Comment: Although I would say that if you have some compound value in which the first four characters are frequently used in a predicate, then the substr method would be appropriate, and can also be indexed. "Virtual columns" would be the feature to investigate. This also extends to queries against SubStr(my_col, 5, 7) etc., for which Like might not be precise enough

Answer (score 6):

Oracle and some other products have `substr`.

```
SELECT * FROM tablename WHERE substr(columnname, 1, 4) = 'abcd'
```

I.e. single quotes for string literals!

ANSI SQL has `substring`:

```
SELECT * FROM tablename WHERE substring(columnname from 1 for 4) = 'abcd'
```

And others have `left`:

```
SELECT * FROM tablename WHERE LEFT(columnname,4) = 'abcd'
```